# ReactNative Rerender when imported value data changes

Tags: react-native

I have a javascript file like this:

`ui.js`

```
import axios from 'axios';

let ui = {
  starting: 'string1',
  register: () => {
    axios.post('apiPath')
    .then(() => {
          ui.starting = 'string2';
    });
  }
}

export default ui;
```

`Home.js`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text} From 'react-native';
import ui from './ui';

export default class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
         <Text>{ui.starting}</Text>
         <Text onPress={()=>ui.register()}>Register</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

If you press register I want the `Home.js` component to re-render, by making a call from within the `ui.js` file.

I know that you can do this with Redux, Flux, etc.. but this is a really simple app and I don't want all of that extra overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a React component is rendered, it will stay unchanged until its own state or props are updated. Passing `ui.starting` doesn't work since the data is only read at the beginning only; your component doesn't care what happen with the value afterward.

To make it work, you have to modify both files:

`ui.js`

```
import axios from 'axios';

let ui = {
  starting: 'string1',
  register: () => {
    axios.post('apiPath')
    .then(() => {
          return 'string2'
    });
  }
}

export default ui;
```

`Home.js`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text} From 'react-native';
import ui from './ui';

export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { text: ui.starting }
  }
  async registerUI = () => {
    const newText = await ui.register();
    this.setState({ text: newText })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
         <Text>{this.state.text}</Text>
         <Text onPress={this.registerUI}>Register</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```